# Обязательно ли класть кнопку отправки в форму?

Tags: html, html5

Подскажите пожалуйста обязательно ли класть `<button>` для отправки в тег `<form>`
Например если я ее вытяну за приделы формы ее можно будет в дальнейшем привязать к форме?
И в чем разница `<input type='button'>` и `<button>` и `<input type='submit'>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

атрибут form для type="submit" указывает на целевую форму вне самой формы.

```
<form id="form" method="post|get" action="action.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
</form>
<input type="submit" form="form" />
```

type="button" не отправляет форму, разве что только если с js. type="submit" - отправляет.